# Changing the image in world texture is not logged in python info console?

Tags: scripting

I want to loop render different hdri's, though can't figure out how to reproduce the step of changing the image. I'd expect another entry in the info log, alas to no avail

[image: pic]

Comment: The default world image  can be found as `bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree.nodes['Environment Texture'].image` this can be set to another image type data ie `bpy.data.images['your_image_name"]`

Comment: Thank you @Ratt any idea where I can *see* that actions happening in order to reproduce?